# Previously-defined variable not working in other parts of test in nightwatchjs

Tags: nightwatch.js, ssh2

I'm using nightwatchjs and the [ssh2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ssh2) npm package to test that a file name is present in a location, and asserting that it's correct.

My code is as follows;

```
var Client = require('ssh2');
var conn = new Client();
var longFileNamePrdArray;


module.exports = {
    before:
    conn.on('ready', function(browser) {
        console.log('Client :: ready');
        conn.sftp(function(err, sftp) {
            if (err) throw err;
            sftp.readdir('parkersreviewcontent/', function (err, list) {
                if (err) throw err;
                list.map(a => a.longname);
                longFileNamePrdArray = list[1].longname;
                conn.end();
            });
        });
    })
    .connect({
        host: '*hostname*',
        port: 22,
        user: '*user*',
        password: '*password*',
    }),
    'Test Zen Reviews production file is listed': function (browser) {
        console.log(longFileNameStgArray);
   },
    'Closing the browser': function (browser)  {
        browser.browserEnd();
    },
};
```

However, this results in **undefined** being outputted for ***longFileNamePrdArray***.

If I move the ***console.log*** command inside the ***before*** code block, then the filename is correctly displayed as follows;

*-rwxr--r--   1        -        -  2492238 Feb 28 06:37 parkers-reviews-staging.xml*

but when I move it outside the ***before*** block and into my test block, it fails with the undefined output.

I thought by defining ***longFileNamePrdArray*** and stating it at the beginning of the test script it work 'carry across' the ***longFileNamePrdArray*** value into the test block, but it's not.

Any help and assistance would be really appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by using the done callback.

So my working code looks like this;

```
var Client = require('ssh2');
var conn = new Client();
var longFileNamePrdArray;

module.exports = {
    before: function(browser, done) {
    conn.on('ready', function(browser) {
        console.log('Client :: ready');
        conn.sftp(function(err, sftp) {
            if (err) throw err;
            sftp.readdir('parkersreviewcontent/', function (err, list) {
                if (err) throw err;
                list.map(a => a.longname);
                longFileNamePrdArray = list[1].longname;
                conn.end();
                done();
            });
        });
    })
    .connect({
        host: '*hostname*',
        port: 22,
        user: '*user*',
        password: '*password*',
    }),
    'Test Zen Reviews production file is listed': function (browser) {
        console.log(longFileNameStgArray);
   },
    'Closing the browser': function (browser)  {
        browser.browserEnd();
    },
};
```